# Regular expression for email in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a regular expression for email in jQuery:

`var regEmail =/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/;`

But it's giving me an error:

> Invalid term [ (after @ symbol)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to escape the `@` char like : `\@`

Answer (score 0):

try to shield '-' afrer 0-9:

`var regEmail =/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/;`

Answer (score 0):

The jquery [validator plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) includes form validations. Let someone else worry about all that mucky stuff. Sorry I don't know how to answer your specific question though. Does it have to be your own regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

```html
var emailID = $("#txtEmail").val();
var expression = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zAZ]{2,4})+$/;
var regex = new RegExp(eidrex);
if (regex.test(emailID))
{
        //do something
}   
                      
else 
{
        //do something
}
```

its wroking jquery for email,if you are working in MVC